# TeamCity: Build chain to test pull requests

Tags: git, continuous-integration, bitbucket, teamcity, pull-request

We have project setup close to following:
components c1, ..., cN, application assembly and autotests are all as separate git repositories

The build chain ensuring that latest revisions are working together with each other are consisting of jobs:

- Build component 1  ...
- Build component N
- Build application assembly (with snapshot dependency on every component)
- Run autotests (with snapshot dependency on assembly)

Now I want to check pull requests for every repository with that build pipeline, is it even possible with teamcity?

I'm not sure it's possible to set appropriate pull-request status when build for component X succeeded, but later assembly or autotests build is failed (too late to update).

I've tried to set-up "fake" builds in the same build chain for components with snapshot dependency on autotests and check PRs via those new builds, but it looks like default branches are used for snapshot dependencies (desired would be: checked branch for changed component and latest master/develop for everything else)

---

I understand it can be easily done with monorepo and single job.